# Undistorting an image with corresponding points in Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I have an image with specific rectangles on it. I want to undistort these rectangles so I can use the pixel distances to estimate real-world distances.

I started out using code I found online, but the resulting images don't seem to match up.
Normal:
[image: pre]

Undistorted image:
[image: post]

Where the blue rectangles are always normal and green is undistorted.
I also tried using the `initUndistortRectifyMap` and `initInverseRectificationMap` function to remap both the image and points with greater success, but one rectangle is still being mapped in a weird way:

[image: pre-rectify]
[image: post-rectify]

## Code

General:

```
img = cv2.imread(str(image))
IMG_SIZE = img.shape[:-1]  # h, w
optimal_camera_matrix, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, IMG_SIZE[::-1], 1, IMG_SIZE[::-1])
maps = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(
        camera_matrix,
        dist_coeffs,
        None,
        optimal_camera_matrix,
        IMG_SIZE[::-1],
        cv2.CV_32FC1,
    )
inv_maps = cv2.initInverseRectificationMap(
        camera_matrix,
        dist_coeffs,
        None,
        optimal_camera_matrix,
        IMG_SIZE[::-1],
        cv2.CV_32FC1,
    )
```

First version:

```
undistorted_image = cv2.undistort(img, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)
undistorted_begin = cv2.undistortPoints(begin, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, None, optimal_camera_matrix).squeeze()
undistorted_end = cv2.undistortPoints(end, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, None, optimal_camera_matrix).squeeze()
```

Second version:

```
undistorted_image = cv2.undistort(img, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, None, optimal_camera_matrix)
undistorted_image = cv2.remap(img, maps[0], maps[1], cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
undistorted_begin = cv2.undistortPoints(begin, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, None, optimal_camera_matrix).squeeze()
undistorted_end = cv2.undistortPoints(end, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, None, optimal_camera_matrix).squeeze()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[undistort points image show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6h9z.png)

it seems work in my opencv cpp code. could u send me your data and parameters?  l will try it.

```
int test_remap() {
std::string src_path = "./calib_data/left05.jpg";
cv::Mat intrinsic = LoadParams("./workspace/intrinsic.yaml").front();
cv::Mat distortion_coeff = LoadParams("./workspace/distortion_coeff.yaml").front();

cv::Mat test_img = cv::imread(src_path);
cv::Mat undistort_img;
cv::Mat map_x, map_y;
cv::Mat intrinsic_copy = intrinsic.clone();
cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(intrinsic, distortion_coeff, cv::Mat(), 
        intrinsic_copy, test_img.size(), CV_32FC1, map_x, map_y);
cv::remap(test_img, undistort_img, map_x, map_y, cv::InterpolationFlags::INTER_LINEAR,
        cv::BorderTypes::BORDER_CONSTANT, 0);

std::vector<cv::Point2f> undistort_pts, to_un{cv::Point2f(241., 97.)};
cv::undistortPoints(to_un, undistort_pts, intrinsic, distortion_coeff, cv::Mat(), intrinsic);
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "undistort_pts " <<  undistort_pts.front() << std::endl;

cv::circle(test_img, to_un.front(), 3, cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
cv::circle(undistort_img, undistort_pts.front(), 3, cv::Scalar(0,255,0));

cv::Mat concat_img;
cv::hconcat(std::vector<cv::Mat>{test_img, undistort_img}, concat_img);
cv::imshow("undistort", concat_img);
cv::waitKey(0);}
```

Comment: Thank you for checking out my idea! Here is a link to the image and code in question.
Image: https://imgur.com/a/VgyqG0f
Code: https://pastebin.com/AD0ZLhZw

Comment: i get the same result. undistort central  rect, object is matching, but the left rect not. you shuld use fisheye model to describe the distortion, pinhole modle doesnt fit this camera. is it 160 degree fisheye?

Comment: According to the datasheet, the horizontal/vertical FoV is 100-53/54-30 degrees and we have the camera set up quite wide. I hope that answers your question. I did try out using the fisheye model and it seems to perform quite nicely, thank you for the tip!

Comment: ok, thats great!